# SQL Server Best Practices Table Linking

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL server and am wanting to make sure I am using best practices. What I am doing is creating 7 tables.

```
(Transaction,Customer,Business,Vehicle,Seller,Lien,Mailto)
```

`Transaction` is my main table where it creates a `TransactionID`. Then in the other 6 tables I will also have a `TransactionID` column so I can link them all together.

In the other 6 tables they each have there own ID as well.

For example

```
(CustomerID, BusinessID, VehicleID, SellerID, LienID, MailtoID)
```

My question is in my transaction table do I have to list all of those `IDs` or does having just the `TransactionID` allow them all to connect.

**Transaction Table 1 Example**

```
ID
Type
DateTime
```

**Transaction Table 2 Example**

```
ID
Type
CustomerID
BusinessID
VehicleID
MailtoID
SellerID
LienID
DateTime
```

(For the transaction ID I am wanting it to be created and then automatically fill the same in for the other tables as those fields are submitted using foreign keys I believe)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to list all of those IDs- NO!.

having just the "TransactionID" allow them all to connect.

Comment: you need a trigger on insert/update (on the transaction table). This trigger will update all other table with the new TransactionID